# Giving a plugin-class a humanly readable name

Tags: c#, plugins, interface

I'm creating a plugin system for my application and I would like for the plugins to expose a humanly readable name. The application will show a list of available plugins, in this list the name need to be available.

I want to make it very clear for the developers of the plugins what they need to do to make their plugins work.

Currently I'm making the plugin-classes implement an interface and the interface require a property "ConsumerName" to be implemented. However, this requires the main application to create an instance of each plugin, in order to use the CunsumerName property, just to show the list.

```
public interface IDataConsumer : IDisposable
{
    string ConsumerName { get; }

    void Consume(DataRowSet rows);

    ...
}
```

Is there any way to force the plugins classes to supply meta-data without creating instances of each type?

My fallback plan is to use reflection and some Attribute on each class, but I don't think that Attributes can be forced using interfaces.

Comment: You should read the name of the plugin from a configuration file that would come along with the said plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, attributes can't be made part of the contract for an interface. But they can be highly recommended.

What I've done in the past is made an attribute such as:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class PluginNameAttribute : Attribute {
    public string ConsumerName { get; set; }
}
```

If a programmer chooses to decorate his class with that attribute, then great. If not, you can fall back on the class name itself:

```
var consumerName = type.Name;
var nameAttribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PluginNameAttribute), true)
    .FirstOrDefault() as PluginNameAttribute;
if (nameAttribute != null) {
    var attributeName = nameAttribute.ConsumerName;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attributeName)) {
        consumerName = attributeName;
    }
}
```

It shouldn't be too much to ask of plugin developers to use the attribute if it's documented that they should do so.

Comment: Nice and simple. What would be a good way of making the attribute class itself discoverable by the plugin developers?

Comment: @PeterHenell - As Jon said, it's always a possibility to throw an exception if a plugin class isn't decorated with the attribute. That way, the first time a developer goes to test his plugin, he'll know immediately that it's required. If that sounds too extreme, then good documentation is probably the answer.

Comment: Throwing an exception is probably what I will do in the end or having some sort of debug window in the application that will show this kind of information.

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would say "no there is not". That's because there are two mechanisms that allow information to be pulled out of types without requiring an instance to be created: `static` members and attributes. Since there is no overlap between these mechanisms and interfaces, you cannot satisfy all of your stated requirements at the same time.

However, what's wrong with the attribute-based solution? Certainly you cannot force the presence of the attribute on pain of a failed compile, but you *can* do that when loading the plugin (or even earlier).